# ngbootstrap 12 with angular 13 ngbnavitem error

Tags: angular13

with angular 13 and ngbootstrap 12 getting following error
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[NgbNavItem -> NgbNavItem -> NgbNavItem]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbNavItem!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do following changes in `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgbNavItem } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

providers [.., NgbNavItem] // add into providers
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot the ngbNavItem.

```
<li>
```

Should be

```
<li ngbNavItem>
```